# How to set the remaining space of a container/view to a color in react native?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, native-base

Edit: For whoever suggesting to remove the *reactjs* tag, my project extends React and removing the tag removes all of the code highlighting making it (plain white) less readable.

I want to set the bottom white color to this '#f4f4f4' which would be the same color as the background color for the save button but I can't seem to do it. I've tried creating another view and add a flex of one to fill it but it wasn't filling the rest of the screen. It just added an extra row instead of filling the remaining space.

```
  render() {
    if (!this.state.isReady) {
      return (
        <View
          style={{
            alignItems: "center",
            justifyContent: "center",
            flex: 1
          }}
        >
          <Progress.Bar indeterminate color={Themes.primaryTheme} />
        </View>
      );
    }
    return (
      <Container>
        <Content>
          <ListItem itemDivider>
            <Text
              style={{
                fontWeight: "500",
                fontSize: 18,
                color: Themes.primaryTheme
              }}
            >
              Show
            </Text>
          </ListItem>
          <ListItem style={{ borderBottomWidth: 0, height: 35 }}>
            <Body>
              <Text>Men</Text>
            </Body>
            <Right>
              <Switch
                thumbColor={Themes.primaryTheme}
                value={this.state.showMen}
                onValueChange={value => this.setState({ showMen: value })}
              />
            </Right>
          </ListItem>
          <ListItem style={{ borderBottomWidth: 0, height: 35 }}>
            <Body>
              <Text>Women</Text>
            </Body>
            <Right>
              <Switch
                thumbColor={Themes.primaryTheme}
                value={this.state.showWomen}
                onValueChange={value => this.setState({ showWomen: value })}
              />
            </Right>
          </ListItem>
          <ListItem style={{ borderBottomWidth: 0, height: 35 }}>
            <Body>
              <Text>Other</Text>
            </Body>
            <Right>
              <Switch
                thumbColor={Themes.primaryTheme}
                value={this.state.showOther}
                onValueChange={value => this.setState({ showOther: value })}
              />
            </Right>
          </ListItem>
          <ListItem itemDivider>
            <Text
              style={{
                fontWeight: "500",
                fontSize: 18,
                color: Themes.primaryTheme
              }}
            >
              Age Range
            </Text>
            <Text style={{ marginTop: 2, marginLeft: 15 }}>
              {`${this.state.minAge} - ${this.state.maxAge}`}
            </Text>
          </ListItem>
          <ListItem style={{ borderBottomWidth: 0 }}>
            <Body>
              <MultiSlider
                selectedStyle={{ backgroundColor: Themes.primaryTheme }}
                containerStyle={{ marginLeft: 20 }}
                markerStyle={{
                  borderWidth: 12,
                  borderColor: Themes.primaryTheme
                }}
                min={18}
                max={100}
                values={[this.state.minAge, this.state.maxAge]}
                onValuesChange={values =>
                  this.setState({ minAge: values[0], maxAge: values[1] })}
              />
            </Body>
          </ListItem>
          <ListItem itemDivider>
            <Text
              style={{
                fontWeight: "500",
                fontSize: 18,
                color: Themes.primaryTheme
              }}
            >
              Other Settings
            </Text>
          </ListItem>
          <ListItem style={{ height: 50 }}>
            <Body>
              <Text>Allow Notifications</Text>
            </Body>
            <Right>
              <Switch
                thumbColor={Themes.primaryTheme}
                value={this.state.showOther}
                onValueChange={value => this.setState({ showOther: value })}
              />
            </Right>
          </ListItem>
          <ListItem itemDivider>
            <Button rounded>
              <Text>Save</Text>
            </Button>
          </ListItem>
          {/* <View style={{ flex: 1, backgroundColor: "#f4f4f4" }} /> */}
        </Content>
      </Container>
    );
  }
```

[image]

Comment: can you share an expo link where we can check and edit?

Comment: are you using native base?

Comment: @GauravRoy https://snack.expo.io/@clu7ch3r/2e5d8a

Comment: @abhikumar22 Yes

Comment: @CLUTCHER please provide a workable expo snack, current one is not working coz dependencies are not installed . i gues

Comment: @GauravRoy I've gotten rid of the errors but I don't think native base works well with snack https://snack.expo.io/@clu7ch3r/settings

Comment: yah ,antive base wont work as it requires linking i suppose

Comment: Try to put style in your <Container style={{background color:"#f4f4f4"}}> to color the rest of the screen

Comment: @CLUTCHER cool, I have posted the comment as an answer. Please accept it as the correct answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to put style in your  to color the rest of the screen:

`<Container style={{ backgroundColor:"#f4f4f4" }}>`